# How do I hook a models timestamps to a user id in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

When defining a model with timestamps (`created_at` and `updated_at`), is there a straight forward way to hook into those update/create methods so the current user's id will be inserted into the model.

I have two extra fields (`created_by_user_id` and `updated_by_user_id`) to store the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the method `save()`:

```
<?php

class Post extends Eloquent {

    public function save()
    {
        if (! $this->exists) 
        {
            $this->created_by_user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        }

        $this->updated_by_user_id = Auth::user()->id;

        parent::save();
    }

}
```

Comment: This is cool. Initially I was going to with my boot method below, but this is more `eloquent` - pardon the pun! Can I suggest that the `$this->updated_by_user_id = Auth::user()->id;` is removed from the `else` because the update would happen on both exists and not exists. To clarify, still have the update part, but just not within the else clause

Answer (score 0):

I found quite a clean way here: 
http://driesvints.com/blog/using-laravel-4-model-events

A snippet that uses the built in model event system in laravel:

```
    public static function boot() {
        parent::boot();

        static::creating(function($cluster) {
            $cluster->created_by_users_id = Auth::user()->id;
            $cluster->updated_by_users_id = Auth::user()->id;
        });

        static::updating(function($cluster) {
            $cluster->updated_by_users_id = Auth::user()->id;
        });
    }
```